# sending command from bash terminal history to $EDITOR

Tags: vim, terminal, command, edit

What would be the easiest way to send previously used command, from bash
history to preffered editor, say VIM.

Right now I am using `fc -l` to see which command I am interested in, then I
isolate it by that line `fc -l lineno lineno | vim -` specifying two times `lineno` to
pick only that line, and send it to VIM.

However this is very time consuming, there must be a better way.

Reason for this is not that I want to re-edit the command, to execute it
again, because that one I know how to do, pressing `CTRL + X + E` will send it
immediately to vim, and re-execute it on `:wq`.

What I want, is to document it, maybe change few things here and there, and
post it as a gist, which I can directly from VIM using Gist plug-in.

Answer (score 2):

How about moving more of the work to Vim? Say you are interested in the last 50 commands and run the following command:

```
fc -nl -50 | sed 's/^\t //' | vim -
```

Now you see all history items and can search through them with `/` or filter out with `:g/bad-line-pattern/d` and `:v/good-line-pattern/d`. If you're used to Vim it's a matter of several key strokes.

After you navigated to the line you need and want to leave only it in the buffer, you could use a shortcut like this one:

```
nnoremap <leader>f VyggVGp
```

It should leave only current line in the buffer.

Comment: this is pretty useful, I would only add `fc -nl -50 | sed 's/^\t //' | vim -`, to override number of history lines sent to vim for processing, as it defaults to 16 I think.

Comment: @branquito, I agree, 16 is strange number in this context, changed it. I was wondering why it outputs this many number of lines, thought it somehow related to commands run in a session. Now I see `man bash` says `-16` is default without explanation, no information in `help fc` on this though.

Answer (score 0):

just do this to put previous command in vim, without re-executing it after save the buffer:

```
fc -ln -1|vim -
```

or

```
history -n -1|vim -
```

Comment: sorry it is not any different from what I was already doing. `fc -l line line` to specify exactly the line I want.

Comment: `However this is very time consuming,` @branquito  this is different. You don't have to check the line numbers, just fire the command, or you can make an alias. It solved your `time consuming` problem or not? or what are you expecting?

Comment: It applies only to last used command.. What if it were somewhere in the middle of history?

Comment: yes, I think you were reffering to last used command, and I needed flexibility of using any of previously used commands in history list ;) anyway thanks for helping!

Comment: @branquito I didn't think in that way, because you need anyway the "eye-scan" step... remove the `-1` in my answer, you whole all list in your vim... anyway, important is your problem gets solved.

Comment: yes you are right, that's why I'm still waiting for some alternative solution, because I already knew how to feed list to Vim. However it was helpful to strip those tabs and spaces from beginning, before sending list to Vim

Comment: Ideally I would like to have same flexibility as one with reverse search finding command, then something like hitting CTRL+X+E, but without executing when going out from Vim.

Comment: @branquito with zsh, after quitting from vim (c-x c-e), the edited cmd is filled there, waiting for your `Enter` :)

Comment: Is there some setting in bash that would make it act like that?